# Printing lines between start & end variables in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script to organize some log files into a human readable format. The idea behind my code is that one could run the script and provide an IP address, and then it would pull all the logs relating to sessions involving that IP. Here's what my code does so far:

```
-takes in external log data 
-takes in an IP address as an argument

-loops through each log
  -if it reaches a log containing the specified IP {
    -find the MSD number within that log
    -check if MSD is in "collected" array
  
    -if MSD is already in array {
      -resume the loop
    } else {
      -add MSD to the "collected" array
      ****-search all logs for corresponding MSD and echo them to output.txt
      -does not affect the order in which the logs were generated
    }
  -add a "--------" visual separator
  -resume loop, repeating the process each time it finds the IP with a new MSD
```

Here's my code:

```
OUTPUT_FILE=./output.txt
ARR=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if grep -q "$1" <<< "$line"; then
    MSD="$(echo "$line" | cut --complement -d '[' -f 1 | cut -d ']' -f 1)"
    if [[ ! " ${ARR[*]} " =~ " ${MSD} " ]] then
      ARR+=($MSD)
      cat ./example_logs | grep $MSD >> $OUTPUT_FILE
      echo "------------------" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
    fi
  fi
done < ./example_logs
```

Here is example input:

```
Apr 12 03:42:45 fe1 msd[2645899]: SMTPD started: connection from 3x.x.xx.xx
Apr 12 00:12:24 fe1 msd[2320005]: SMTPD started: connection from 46.xxx.xxx.xxx
Apr 12 00:12:24 fe1 msd[2320005]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 00:01:39 fe1 msd[2319095]: SMTPD started: connection from 85.xxx.xxx.xxx
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: SMTPD started: connection from 173.xxx.xxx.xx
Apr 12 00:01:39 fe1 msd[2319095]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 03:42:45 fe1 msd[2645899]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 00:12:24 fe1 msd[2320005]: CONN: 46.xxx.xxx.xxx -> 587 GeoIP = [LV] PTR = ....... 
Apr 12 00:01:39 fe1 msd[2319095]: CONN: 85.xxx.xxx.xxx -> 587 GeoIP = [NL] PTR = .......
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 00:12:24 fe1 msd[2320005]: EHLO command received, args: .......
... (400 more lines)
```

Here is a snippet of the current output:

```
#EXAMPLE LOGS (target IP is 3x.x.xx.xx)
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: SMTPD started: connection from 173.xxx.xxx.xx 
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Session ending: Client was hardblocked
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Exiting (bytes in: 14 out: 90)
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406939]: SMTPD started: connection from 3x.x.xx.xx 
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406939]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 04:04:35 fe1 msd[2406939]: CONNECTED using SSL
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406939]: Session ending: Client issued QUIT
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406939]: Exiting (bytes in: 149 out: 389)
```

My issue is where I marked **** (the cat line)... From the output, you can see that there are two IPs that share the same MSD. I don't know how to go about removing the logs that I don't need. Any suggestions? So far I've tried creating $START and $END variables, but I'm sure I'm not doing this properly...

```
TARGET="connection from $1"
START="$(grep "$MSD" example_logs | grep "$TARGET")"
END="$(grep "$MSD" example_logs | grep -i "exiting")"
```

EDIT: I posted my janky solution to my own problem below, in case someone wants to know where I ended up with this.

Comment: You need to provide a reduced sample logfile, preferably containing the possible border cases. For resolving this kind of problem, you generally search the input file for a logic to base your code on.

Comment: Unless you are *concatenating* two (or more) files, `cat file` is an *Unnecessary Use of `cat`* (*UUOc*) and should be avoided. Instead just read the file, or use redirection. `grep example_logs "$MSD" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"` would be the proper way (also *quote your variables*) -- But avoid calling it every iteration within a loop -- that tells you you need to refactor your code and do something different in most cases.

Comment: Good to know, @DavidC.Rankin ! This is the first bash script I've ever written, so I ended up just stitching stackoverflow solutions together until I got a decent outcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the janky solution I came up with after 3 cups of coffee & 15 hours of coding. I hope it might be useful to someone else out there!

```sh
rm ./output.txt
OUTPUT_FILE=./output.txt
#
#
# ================= PART 1: =================
# An empty array for values later
MSD_ARR=()
#
# Loop through each log in ./output_logs
#   -IF it reaches a log containing the target IP {
#       -find msd# within that log & save to variable
#       -check if current msd is in MSD_ARR
#
#       -IF current msd is NOT in the array {
#           -add msd to MSD_ARR
#           -grep all logs containing the current msd
#           -output logs to new file. Does not affect the order in which logs are listed.
#       } else {
#           -resume the loop.  
#       }
#    }
#
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if grep -q "$1" <<< "$line"; then
    MSD="$(echo "$line" | cut --complement -d '[' -f 1 | cut -d ']' -f 1)"
    if [[ ! " ${MSD_ARR[*]} " =~ " ${MSD} " ]]; then
      MSD_ARR+=($MSD)
      cat ./example_logs | grep $MSD >> $OUTPUT_FILE
      echo "------------------------" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
    fi
  fi
done < ./example_logs
#
#
# ================= PART 2: =================
#
# Loop through each log in ./output.txt
#   -IF it reaches a log containing the phrase "connection from" {
#       -find msd# within that log & save to variable
#       -IF the current log does NOT contain the target IP {
#           -grab the current line's position & save as a variable called "START"
#           -grab all positions of lines containing the phrase "Exiting" & split the values into an array called "EndArr"
#
#           -FOR LOOP over EndArr
#           -IF our START position is less than (comes before) our current END position (EndVal) {
#               use "sed" to delete logs, using START and EndVal as the range. Deletes inclusively
#               BREAK out of this loop to repeat the process with the next START value
#           }
#       }
#   }
#
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if grep -q "connection from" <<< "$line"; then
    MSD="$(echo "$line" | cut --complement -d '[' -f 1 | cut -d ']' -f 1)"
    if [[ ! " ${line} " =~ " ${1} " ]]; then
      START="$(awk -v var="$line" 's=index($0,var){print NR}' output.txt)"
      END="$(awk -v var="Exiting" 'e=index($0,var){print NR}' output.txt)"
      EndArr=($END)
      for EndVal in "${EndArr[@]}"; do
        if [ "$START" -lt "$EndVal" ]; then
          sed -i "$START,$EndVal d" ./output.txt
          break
        fi
      done
    fi
  fi
done < ./output.txt
#
# ===========================================
# EXAMPLE USE:
# >bash filename [IP Address]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done with a simple call to `awk` and three rules. (each rule is specified as `condition { commands }`) Without a `condition` the rule is run for every record (input line) Essentially all you need to do is:

1. get the 7-digit `msd` from the 5th field (e.g. `msd[xxxxxxx]`);
2. if not the first line and the msd isn't the same as the last, output your `"------------------"` separator
3. output the current line, and update your `last` variable with the current `msd`

To save to your `"$OUTPUT_FILE"`, just redirect the output of the command.

If you put that together in a short `awk` script, you have:

```sh
awk '
  { # separate digits from msd[xxx] and save as msd
    # set RSTART RLENGHT (index and length of digits)
    match ($5,/[[:digit:]]+/)
    msd = substr($5,RSTART,RLENGTH)   # assign substring of digits to msd
  }
  FNR > 1 && last != msd {  # if line > 1 and msd has changed
    print "------------------"
  }
  {
    print           # output line
    last = msd      # update last with msd
  }
' file > "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

**Example Use/Output**

Since you only have one `msd` in your example data, there is no change in `msd` to catch. For example purposes the data has been duplicated and the `msd` changed, e.g.

```
$ cat file
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: SMTPD started: connection from 173.xxx.xxx.xx
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Session ending: Client was hardblocked
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Exiting (bytes in: 14 out: 90)
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406939]: SMTPD started: connection from 3x.x.xx.xx
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406939]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 04:04:35 fe1 msd[2406939]: CONNECTED using SSL
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406939]: Session ending: Client issued QUIT
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406939]: Exiting (bytes in: 149 out: 389)
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: SMTPD started: connection from 173.xxx.xxx.xx
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: Session ending: Client was hardblocked
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: Exiting (bytes in: 14 out: 90)
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406940]: SMTPD started: connection from 3x.x.xx.xx
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406940]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 04:04:35 fe1 msd[2406940]: CONNECTED using SSL
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406940]: Session ending: Client issued QUIT
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406940]: Exiting (bytes in: 149 out: 389)
```

Now running the script produces the following with your separator at the `msd` transition:

```sh
$ awk '
>   { # separate digits from msd[xxx] and save as msd
>     # set RSTART RLENGHT (index and length of digits)
>     match ($5,/[[:digit:]]+/)
>     msd = substr($5,RSTART,RLENGTH)   # assign substring of digits to msd
>   }
>   FNR > 1 && last != msd {  # if line > 1 and msd has changed
>     print "------------------"
>   }
>   {
>     print           # output line
>     last = msd      # update last with msd
>   }
> ' file
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: SMTPD started: connection from 173.xxx.xxx.xx
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Session ending: Client was hardblocked
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406939]: Exiting (bytes in: 14 out: 90)
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406939]: SMTPD started: connection from 3x.x.xx.xx
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406939]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 04:04:35 fe1 msd[2406939]: CONNECTED using SSL
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406939]: Session ending: Client issued QUIT
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406939]: Exiting (bytes in: 149 out: 389)
------------------
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: SMTPD started: connection from 173.xxx.xxx.xx
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: Session ending: Client was hardblocked
Apr 12 01:04:20 fe1 msd[2406940]: Exiting (bytes in: 14 out: 90)
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406940]: SMTPD started: connection from 3x.x.xx.xx
Apr 12 04:04:34 fe1 msd[2406940]: Created UUID ....... for message
Apr 12 04:04:35 fe1 msd[2406940]: CONNECTED using SSL
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406940]: Session ending: Client issued QUIT
Apr 12 04:04:37 fe1 msd[2406940]: Exiting (bytes in: 149 out: 389)
```

It's not entirely clear from your question what you want to use `TARGET`, `START` and `END` for, so if I've misinterpreted what you were trying to do, update your question with further explanation and drop a comment below.

Using `awk` for this instead of a shell script and loop will be *Orders of Magnitude* more efficient. (with differences as big as a few seconds with `awk` compared to a few hours of runtime with the shell script for large logs)

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't included any of the input example logs originally - I've now added some to my original post. The log file contains 400 logs with 35 different MSD numbers, and 4 IP addresses. The idea behind my code is that one could run the script and provide an IP address, and then it would pull all the logs relating to sessions involving that IP. Because I used the MSD number to grab the related logs, it included some logs from different IPs that happened to share the same MSD. The START and END make a range for the extra logs that I wanted to delete from the final output.